# How to store data/parameters in html using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, web

If I have a comment thread, and I want to reply to the comment thread I would have to

```
  return $http.post('/reply/', {
    user: username,
    test: text ,
    parent: parent
  }).then(registerSuccessFn, registerErrorFn);
```

The html would be something in the line of

```
  <form role="form" ng-submit="vm.reply()">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="user">User</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" ng-model="vm.user" placeholder="ex. john" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="text">text</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text" ng-model="vm.text" placeholder="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="parent">parent</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="parent" ng-model="vm.parent" placeholder="parent" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

But the thing is that parent, and the user should be dynamically generated, how do I generate the form dynamically so that each form in html correctly stores the parameter for parent and user such that it reflect the parent of the post and user comment on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the page the form is on (or alternatively just the form itself) to a controller e.g. MyFormController. Then when initially loading the page/form, make sure to load the `parent` and `user` information and store in your `$scope.vm` model.
NB - I'm of course assuming that you have the `parent` and `user` information in your database since you said they will be dynamically generated.

```
var loadData = function () {
  $http.get(user_url).success(function (user) {
    $scope.vm.user = user;
  });
  $http.get(parent_url).success(function (parent) {
    $scope.vm.parent = parent;
  });
};
loadData();
```

That's about all you'll need to do and the data will be binded to your form.

Cheers